# how to get functions stored inside of a property in Python?

Tags: python, reflection

Suppose `prop = property(fget = somefunc1, fset = somefunc2)`

How would I get `somefunc1` and `somefunc2`, given `prop`?

```
getter = ?
setter = ?


if (getter == None):
    do something
else:
    do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do. But can't you just access `prop.fget` and `prop.fset` ?

```
>>> def somefunc1(): pass
...
>>> def somefunc2(): pass
...
>>> prop = property(fget = somefunc1, fset = somefunc2)
>>> getter = prop.fget
>>> setter = prop.fset
>>>
>>> getter
<function somefunc1 at 0x023085B0>
>>> setter
<function somefunc2 at 0x023085F0>
```

Comment: yup, just figured that out by printing the attributes. Wasn't sure if fget and fset were the actual attributes or not.

Comment: Yep, I use `dir()` in the interactive shell all the time to figure things like that out.

Comment: ...or just type `smth.` and press `TAB` in an ipython session.